# Identical rewrite rules for multiple websites in apache.conf

Tags: mod-rewrite, virtualhost, apache-config

I'm trying to setup multiple websites in `Apache.conf` to include identical RewriteRules, and avoid having to use `.htaccess` files in the root dir of each website. The websites are all running the same application, and the `.htaccess` files are identical. This post gets a bit long so please bear with me.

Applying the rules separately to each directory basically **WORKS**:

```
<Directory /var/www/sites/sitename/>
# Rewrite any calls to *.html, *.json, *.xml, *.atom, *.rss, *.rdf or *.txt if a folder matching * exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1.$2 !-f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(html|json|xml|atom|rss)$ $1/ [L]

# Add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|\?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ $1/ [L]

# Rewrite any calls to /render to the image parser
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} render/
RewriteRule ^render/. app/parsers/slir/ [L]

# Rewrite routes to index.php if they are non-existent files/dirs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?/$1/ [L,QSA]

# Rewrite any file calls to the public directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/$1 [L]

# Allow basic authentication
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</Directory>
```

I have 20+ websites that require the same rules, so it seems pretty ineffective having to include the entire block above for each directory. I have tried a few things, and although I feel I'm onto something, they produce wrong results:

```
<DirectoryMatch /var/www/sites/[^/]+/>
{{ RULES_BE_HERE }}
</DirectoryMatch>
<Directory /var/www/sites/.*/>
RewriteBase /
{{ RULES_BE_HERE }}
</DirectoryMatch>
```

The best solution I can come up with, is using an Apache include file for each directory like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/sites/site1/>
  Include /etc/apache2/myrules.conf
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/sites/site2/>
  Include /etc/apache2/myrules.conf
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/sites/site3/>
  Include /etc/apache2/myrules.conf
</Directory>
```

Obviously I don't have too much experience with apache.conf and rewrite rules. Anyone has any sound advice? Any help appreciated.

Comment: An include file is absolutely a good approach to this!

Comment: However what I don't understand is why you want to place it inside some `<Directory>` block. Why not define those rule for the hosts in general?

Comment: And a hint: take care when moving rules from dynamic configuration files into the real http servers host configuration: rewrite rules in there work on _absolute_ paths, while they work on _relative_ paths in dynamic configuration files.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The reason I wanted to add into a `<Directory>` block would be to achieve the same rule on multiple sub-directories. I have plenty of other settings (deflate, headers, deny etc.) inside a global block `<Directory /var/www/sites/>` that work perfectly, but not rewriterules, as they seem to be somehow affected/relative to the path set in `<Directory>`. Regarding relative/absolute paths, the rewrite rules certainly seem to be working *relative* to the directory path defined ...

Comment: You don't need to double a rule set to apply it to multiple locations. That is a question of how to phrase the matching patterns. Settings inside a `<Directory>` block can hardly be called "global", can they? And finally: for the relative/absolute path issue: I suggest you read the documentation of the rewriting module, I think that will clear up a few things.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I have a lot of settings inside a single <Directory> block that applies to a dozen websites. Sounds pretty global to me ...

Comment: Things _outside_ a `<Directory>` block are considered rules applied global to a _host_, not a location.

Comment: Ok, let's call it a 'scope' then. I don't want it applied to ALL servers, just a dozen+ under a directory path. This is not the point.

Comment: Ok, sorry, maybe I got this all wrong. I only wanted to save you from making things overly complex.